# Contact form sends but response comes back as an XML fire error.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

When I submit a contact form on my site http://dsrp.tv/index-preview.php (click the "choose your poison" coffee choice in the footer) I get the following errors:

1. A white page that says:

   This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

   1
   Thank you, I will reply shortly.
2. An error:

   Uncaught TypeError:

   Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'display' in null jquery.js:3

   At jquery.js:3

   ```
   x.extend.css jquery.js:3
   Lt jquery.js:3
   An jquery.js:4
   jn jquery.js:4
   s jquery.js:4
   x.extend.dequeue jquery.js:3
   (anonymous function) jquery.js:3
   x.extend.each jquery.js:2
   x.fn.x.each jquery.js:2
   x.fn.extend.queue jquery.js:3
   x.fn.extend.animate jquery.js:4
   x.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.js:4
   (anonymous function)
   ```

I'm not sure what else to try? Any ideas or areas to investigate?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you are trying to make an AJAX call from within a form, which won't work.  When you configure the form "action"  and "method"field, you are telling it to navigate to that url with the http method (POST) and do a full page render of what is returned.

What you want to do is make the modal a set of input boxes (without the "form" element), submit an ajax request when the "send" button is pressed, then re-render the modal using the data returned from the ajax request (should be passed to the "success" function).

Comment: This is probably correct but I've used the same form on other sites (attorneyrus.com). Is it something unique about using a modal? I really have a lot more to learn about ajax. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do I do this part: "submit an ajax request when the "send" button is pressed"?

Comment: I have it setup but I just don't know how to trigger everything. Can someone throw me a bone please?